# Stop UITextField resizing when setting text

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a view setup with 4 UITextFields laid out and constraints setup so that it's looking great on all devices and working as expected.  I have an issue where by if I set the text using TextField.text = @" some long text "; or [TextField setText:@"some long text"]; it causes the textfield to expand its width to fit the length of the text and then because of the constraints the other textfields resize too.

How can I stop the textfield resizing ? What I would like is the field to stay the same and the user to be able to just scroll the text If they want to get to the end?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just need to change the constraints. Give the UITextField an explicit internal Width constraint (or use constraints to set or limit its width in some other way) and then things will behave as you desire.

Remember, in general *all* aspects of a view's size and position *must* be unambiguously configured by its constraints. Right now, however, your text field has *no* Width constraint, so its width is based on its text contents (that is, it uses the *intrinsic content size* to obtain its width). Omitting the Width constraint is not illegal, which is why Interface Builder did not complain when you set up the constraints - but it is legal only because there is an intrinsic content size that supplies a width, and thus it does mean that the width changes if the internal text changes. If that isn't what you want, then don't do that - supply an explicit Width constraint instead.

(Similarly, a text field has an implicit height of 30, which is why you do not have to give it a Height constraint. This height does *not* change with the text contents, because, unlike a UILabel, a text field does not wrap its text onto multiple lines.)

Comment: Thanks, adding a width constraint sorted it, although on iPhone 6 it then caused bigger gaps at the sides than I wanted compared to the 5s.  I've now added left/right constraints from container edges and it works perfectly

Comment: Perfect. That is what I meant by "use constraints to set or limit its width in some other way"!

Comment: Had a different problem and saw the implicit height constraint but couldn't believe that such a thing would be added by UIKit. Especially in the context of dynamic type, this implicit 30pt constraint is really painful. Thanks for mentioning this, I wouldn't have believed it for another couple of days ;-)

Comment: Would it be bad to give a number for the width of the textfield say 40?  I was under the impression it is bad to use these magic numbers.

Comment: @bakalolo is 40 the height you want? Great! Set it.  There is no inherent issue with using static figures to define constraints like these.  If you want your text field at 40 across all device sizes and conditions then this is a fine solution.  If you want your text field to be say 10% of the screen at all times, then, well, this is not the right solution.  If you want it to dynamically resize vertically to it's contents then again this is probably not the solution.

Comment: @bakalolo one more quick note, a common draw back to using these magic numbers is maintainability.  If you are using 10 text fields all set at a height of 40 well then thats a pain.  If working programmatically try extracting this height to a variable for greater ease-of-use.