# TextField height not automatically updated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have made a TableView, in which I set

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

In one cell, I place a view, in which I drag a label, and for that label, I set constraints to top and bottom equal to view top and bottom. I increase the font of the label to 150. The table view cell scales nicely.

In the second cell, I place a view, in which I drag a textfield, and for that textfield, I set constraints to top and bottom equal to view top and bottom. I increase the font of the textfield to 150. The table view cell does not scale nicely, but keeps as small as my estimated row height.

How is this possible? Which properties should I set additionally for the textfield?

I am using iOS 9.0 as Deployment target. Below are a screenshot of the constraints and a screenshot of the simulator how it currently looks like.

[image: Constraints of the TextField]

[image: Second cell scales, first and third cell do not scale]

Comment: Have you tried using `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` instead, and calculating what you need there?

Comment: I have not, but isn't the whole point of auto-layout that I shouldn't do these calculations in code? Or do I misunderstand what to do with that method?

Comment: I never use auto-layout, so I'm not sure. You may be right.

Comment: try this tutorial https://mkswap.net/m/ios/2015/07/08/uitableviewcells-with-dynamic-height.html

Comment: Show the constraints for the cell with the UITextField

Comment: So you want each cell to be sized to fit its respecting lable's text size?

Comment: @Mr T.: In that tutorial, they also explicitly calculate the height of the cell. That is in my example not necessary for the cell with the label, and I can't believe it's necessary for this cell.

Comment: @beyowulf: I have added a screenshot of the constraints.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, although in the last cell, the element inside the view is not a label but a TextField.

Comment: See @matt's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440563/stop-uitextfield-resizing-when-setting-text as to why you uitextfields don't behave like uilabels and why your cells are not resizing.

Comment: Or you setting font size in code or storyboard. ? If in code please share that Code.

Comment: I am setting the font size in storyboard. I see in the answer you reference to that the textfield does not wrap lines, which is fine in this case. I still don't understand however why it cannot use the intrinsic height of the textfield, based on the text and font that I give it in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

`Tableview` does grow with `textfield`. You might not be setting correct `font family`.

In **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
[cell.yourTextField setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:120]];
```

The cell height increased:

[image]

Try this and let me know if it worked. I played a lot with it.

Hope this can help.